# Load the address of a symbol using NASM?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I have some assembly that needs to load a C symbol in OS X (x86-64).  With x86, the way you do this is:

```
mov rax, some_symbol_name
```

However, with x86-64, this causes a link warning:

> ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _main from Test2.o.
>   To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie

Note: I know what PIE is, and I don't want to disable it.  Here are some of my other attempts to load the symbol address into a register:

```
movq rax, some_symbol_name          ; Link warning
lea rax, [rel some_symbol_name]     ; No link warning, but doesn't always get correct address
```

I'm really stumped on this (seemingly) simple problem.  I've looked at the GAS disassembly, and it seems to be doing something along the lines of the `lea` above, but I can't get NASM to generate the right code.

EDIT: For reference, this is the assembly code generated by GAS:

```
leaq    some_symbol_name(%rip), %rax
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NASM issue on OSX 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814930/nasm-issue-on-osx-64-bit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to force NASM to use RIP relative addressing. Do one of:

```
lea rax, [rel some_symbol_name]
```

or:

```
default rel
lea rax, [some_symbol_name]
```

If this doesn't work, post the machine code generated by both NASM and GAS.

Comment: I have tried both of these options, and they sometimes result in an incorrect address being computed.  This _should_ be the correct solution, but I think there is a bug in the OS X version of NASM for x86-64.

Comment: @MattFichman: Indeed, there was a NASM 2.11.08  bug on OS X that affected RIP-relative addressing: [NASM issue on OSX 64-bit](//stackoverflow.com/q/30814930)