# NASM 64-bit OS X Inputted String Overwriting Bytes of Existing Value

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to write a simple assembly program to add two numbers together. I want the user to be able to enter the values. The problem I am encountering is that when I display a string message and then read a value in, the next time the string is required the first x characters of the string have been overwritten by the data that was entered by the user.

My assumption is that this is related to the use of `LEA` to load the string into the register. I have been doing this because Macho64 complains if a regular `MOV` instruction is used in this situation (something to do with addressing space in 64-bits on the Mac).

My code is as follows:

```
    section .data                                   ;this is where constants go

    input_message db   'Please enter your next number: '
    length equ $-input_message

    section .text                                   ;declaring our .text segment

    global _main                                    ;telling where program execution should start

    _main:                                          ;this is where code starts getting executed
            mov r8, 0
    _loop_values:
            call _get_value
            call _write
            inc r8                                  ;increment the loop counter
            cmp r8, 2                               ;compare loop counter to zero
            jne _loop_values
            call _exit

    _get_value:
            lea rcx, [rel input_message]            ;move the input message into rcx for function call
            mov rdx, length                         ;load the length of the message for function call
            call _write
            call _read
            ret

    _read:
            mov rdx, 255                            ;set buffer size for input
            mov rdi, 0                              ;stdout
            mov rax, SYSCALL_READ
            syscall
            mov rdx, rax                            ;move the length from rax to rdx
            dec rdx                                 ;remove new line character from input length
            mov rcx, rsi                            ;move the value input from rsi to rcx
            ret

    _write:
            mov rsi, rcx                            ;load the output message
            ;mov rdx, rax
            mov rax, SYSCALL_WRITE
            syscall
            ret

    _exit:
            mov rax, SYSCALL_EXIT
            mov rdi, 0
            syscall
```

The program loops twice as it should. The first time I get the following prompt:

`Please enter your next number:`

I would the enter something like `5` (followed by the return key)

The next prompt would be:

`5
ease enter your next number:`

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the same buffer for your prompt and for your input data - so after the first input of "5" you have overwritten the first two characters of the prompt. Try using a separate input buffer for input.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean - is the register `RSI` not used to provide the output for a system write and also where the input is stored after a system read? I didn't know this could be customised?

I did think about attempting to store the `Please input` string in another register (say `R10`) but because of the way it is loaded using `LEA` then as soon as it is moved to `RSI` the same issue occurs (as it is storing the address to memory for the string rather than the value in the register).

Is there a way to use/copy the string without using `LEA`?

Comment: Mac use relative addressing, in AT&T syntax you must use something like `lea str(%rip), %rsi`. (str is my string label and %rsi is my destination.)

Comment: So for my code it would be something like:

`lea %rsi, input_message(%rip)`?

I'm not quite sure why the instruction pointer is involved though?

Comment: `rsi` is pointing at the same buffer (`input_message`) for both your write and subsequent read. You need a second buffer for the read (call it e.g. `input_buffer`) and then point `rsi` at this second buffer prior to the read. That way the characters you read won't overwrite the prompt stored in `input_message`. See the OS X example on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all 64-bit code on Mac is required to be rip relative.
Absolute addresses are not supported. in this type of addressing you address your symbol relative to rip.
NASM documentation says:

```
default abs
mov eax,[foo] ; 32−bit absolute disp, sign−extended
mov eax,[a32 foo] ; 32−bit absolute disp, zero−extended
mov eax,[qword foo] ; 64−bit absolute disp

default rel
mov eax,[foo] ; 32−bit relative disp
mov eax,[a32 foo] ; d:o, address truncated to 32 bits(!)
mov eax,[qword foo] ; error
mov eax,[abs qword foo] ; 64−bit absolute disp
```

and you can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722159/load-the-address-of-a-symbol-nasm-64-bit-os-x).