# NASM issue on OSX 64-bit

Tags: macos, assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I'm learning ASM and I have a small problem.
I can't "declare" more than one string in "section.data".
I'm trying something like this:

```
section .data
    string1 db "test1 ", 0;
    string2 db "test2 ", 0;
section .text
    global _test
    extern _puts
    _test:
         lea rdi, [rel string1]
         call _puts
         lea rdi, [rel string2]
         call _puts
         ret
```

This function is supposed to print "test1 test2 " on STDOUT, but it doesn't work.
The result is:

```
test2
```

It only works for the last string stored! If someone know why, please tell me!

Comment: Let me guess... Nasm-2.11.08? It has a bad bug with `-f macho64`. Go back to 2.11.06. 2.11.09 should be along soon and should fix it... if all goes well. These things happen... :(

Comment: @FrankKotler - this is arcane knowledge. An (expanded?) answer might help others.

Comment: I haven't been "active" as a developer  for quite some time, but I'm still on the list. Scroll down a bit here and there's some explanation of what went wrong. http://sourceforge.net/p/nasm/mailman/nasm-devel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `nasm` 2.11.08, there is a issue documented [here](http://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392306)  to do with relative addressing combined with multiple entries in the data section.

You can do one (or both) of two things to be certain.

First, you can have a look at the generated assembler code to investigate what it's *actually* churning out. That's probably the definitive option since you can then see exactly what the CPU will be running.

Second, you can test your code with an *earlier* release of `nasm` to see if the problem goes away. If so, that's indirect evidence that it's the bug in 2.11.08 causing your issues.