# Successive sys_write syscalls not working as expected, NASM bug on OS X?

Tags: macos, assembly, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64

I'm trying to learn MacOS assembly using NASM and I can't get a trivial program to work. I'm trying a variation of the "Hello, World" where the two words are independently called by a macro. My source code looks like this:

```
%macro printString 2
    mov     rax, 0x2000004 ; write
    mov     rdi, 1 ; stdout
    mov     rsi, %1
    mov     rdx, %2
    syscall
%endmacro     

global start    

section .text    

start:
    printString str1,str1.len    

    printString str2,str2.len    

    mov     rax, 0x2000001 ; exit
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall    


section .data    

str1:   db      "Hello,",10,
.len:  equ       $ - str1    

str2:   db      "world",10
.len:  equ       $ - str2
```

The expected result should be:

```
$./hw
Hello,
World
$
```

Instead I get:

```
$./hw
Hello,
$
```

What am I missing? How do I fix it?

**EDIT**: I am compiling & running with the following commands:

```
/usr/local/bin/nasm -f macho64 hw.asm
ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -lSystem -o hw hw.o
./hw
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NASM 2.11.08 and 2.13.02+ have bugs with `macho64` output. What you are observing seems to be something I saw specifically with 2.13.02+ recently when using absolute references. The final linked program has incorrect fixups applied so the reference to `str2` is incorrect. The incorrect fixup causes us to print out memory that isn't `str2`.

NASM has a [bug report](https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392468#c6) about this issue in their system. I have added a specific example of this failure based on the code in the question. Hopefully the NASM developers will be able to reproduce the failure and create a fix.

**Update**: As of June 2018 my view is that there are enough recurring bugs and regressions in NASM that I do not recommend NASM at this point in time for Macho-64 development.

---

Another recommendation I have for Macho-64 development is to use RIP relative addressing rather than absolute. RIP relative addressing is the default for 64-bit programs on later versions of MacOS.

In NASM you can use the `default rel` directive in your file to change the default from absolute to RIP relative addresses. For this to work you will have to change from using `mov register, variable` to `lea register, [variable]` when trying to move the address of a variable to a register. Your revised code could look like:

```
default rel

%macro printString 2
    mov     rax, 0x2000004 ; write
    mov     rdi, 1 ; stdout
    lea     rsi, [%1]
    mov     rdx, %2
    syscall
%endmacro

global start

section .text

start:
    printString str1,str1.len

    printString str2,str2.len

    mov     rax, 0x2000001 ; exit
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall


section .data

str1:   db      "Hello,",10
.len:  equ       $ - str1

str2:   db      "world",10
.len:  equ       $ - str2
```

Comment: RIP relative addressing worked perfectly! Thank you!!

Comment: @TheSauralph: May I ask what version of nasm you are using. You can use the `-v` option to display it. I am curious what versions of NASM people are using that don't work.

Comment: The version I'm using is NASM version 2.13.03 compiled on Feb  8 2018

Comment: The NASM 2.11.08 bug [was with RIP-relative addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814930/nasm-issue-on-osx-64-bit).  So there's no portable way that's safe on all NASM versions!  Might be worth mentioning that to avoid confusion.  (Of course the best thing is to use a non-buggy NASM version [and RIP-relative instead of 64-bit absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300844/mach-o-64-bit-format-does-not-support-32-bit-absolute-addresses-nasm-accessing).)